# What user information exactly is stored in session after a user is authenticated?

Tags: laravel

Laravel documentation states, [When using a web browser, a user will provide their username and password via a login form. If these credentials are correct, the application will store information about the authenticated user in the user's session.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#:%7E:text=When%20using%20a%20web%20browser%2C%20a%20user%20will%20provide%20their%20username%20and%20password%20via%20a%20login%20form.%20If%20these%20credentials%20are%20correct%2C%20the%20application%20will%20store%20information%20about%20the%20authenticated%20user%20in%20the%20user%27s%20session.:%7E:text=When%20using%20a%20web%20browser%2C%20a%20user%20will%20provide%20their%20username%20and%20password%20via%20a%20login%20form.%20If%20these%20credentials%20are%20correct%2C%20the%20application%20will%20store%20information%20about%20the%20authenticated%20user%20in%20the%20user%27s%20session.)

I logged in and checked the session file in `storage/framework/sessions` and this is what is there `a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"oapalrThHI5GgJqLsXiwHiolPuktxS4enIzXGaCT";s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:43:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/blog/create";}s:50:"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d";i:2;}`

I'm curious, about what user info exactly gets stored there as I don't see anything familiar. Or is the info encrypted? Shining some light on this is highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: this looks like output from `serialize()`, so try to `deserialize()` and peek.

Comment: I don't see `deserialize()`  function in Laravel. How to go about it, please?

Comment: I meant https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php